# File from Response not updating data after each request

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, service, httpresponse

I am very new to C#, I am working in a program than downloads a file data with data from SQL Server database, the issue the query it always brings the same old now nonexistent data in the file.

This is the services BORA.asmx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using LST.Enums;
using LST.Extensions;
using LST.Global;
using LST.Methods;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Diagnostics.Tracing;

namespace BORA
{


        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public byte[] generateReport()
        {
            var vUser = Session["rep-users"];
            var vCat = Session["rep-categories"];
            var vStatus = Session["rep-status"];
            var vAreas = Session["rep-areas"];



            string strWhere = "";

            if (vUser.fwEmpty() != "")
                strWhere += (strWhere == "" ? "" : " AND ") + "P.Owner IN (" + vUser.ToString().fwSqlFilterIn() + ")";

            if (vCat.fwEmpty() != "")
                strWhere += (strWhere == "" ? "" : " AND ") + "Category IN (" + vCat.ToString().fwSqlFilterIn() + ")";

            if (vStatus.fwEmpty() != "")
                strWhere += (strWhere == "" ? "" : " AND ") + "P.Status IN (" + vStatus.ToString().fwSqlFilterIn() + ")";

            if (vAreas.fwEmpty() != "")
                strWhere += (strWhere == "" ? "" : " AND ") + "Area IN (" + vAreas.ToString().fwSqlFilterIn() + ")";

            if (strWhere != "") strWhere = " WHERE " + strWhere;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("strWhere = " + strWhere);

            LST.Methods.clsMethodsWeb fw = new clsMethodsWeb();
            string strPathOrigin = fw.appGetPath + "excel\\template.xlsx";
            string strPathDest = fw.appGetPath + "excel\\{0}.xlsx".fwFormat(Session["User"].ToString().ToLower().Replace(".", ""));
            string strTable = "";
            string strPID = "";

            strPID = "WHERE PID IN (" +
                @"SELECT P.PID
                FROM tbl_Project_Tasks P
                LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Project_Details D
                ON P.PID = D.PID {0}"
                .fwFormat(strWhere)
                .fwSqlFillDataTable()
                .fwDistinctValues("PID")
                .fwSqlFilterIn() + ")";

            if (strPID.fwEmpty() == "") return null;

            fw.fileCopy(strPathOrigin, strPathDest);

            DataTable dt = @"SELECT *
                FROM tbl_Project_Tasks {0}"
                .fwFormat(strPID)
                .fwSqlFillDataTable();




            dt.TableName = "Tasks";
            strTable = "tblTasks";
            LST.EPP.stcEpp.exportToByteArray(new DataTable[] { dt },
                strPathDest, strTable: strTable, blnSave: true);



            // ** Tasks
            dt = @"SELECT *
                FROM tbl_Project_Details D
                LEFT OUTER JOIN  tbl_Project_SavingType S
                ON D.PID = S.PID
                {0}"
                .fwFormat(strPID.Replace(" PID ", " D.PID "))
                .fwSqlFillDataTable();
            dt.TableName = "Projects";
            strTable = "tblProjects";
            LST.EPP.stcEpp.exportToByteArray(new DataTable[] { dt }, strPathDest, strTable: strTable, blnSave: true);
            // ** Projects



            dt = @"SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(SavingType, '(', ''), ')', '') Project, SUM(Saving) Projected, SUM(SavingFinal) Confirmed
                FROM tbl_Project_SavingType
                {0}
                GROUP BY SavingType"
                .fwFormat(strPID)
                .fwSqlFillDataTable();
            dt.TableName = "Project consolidate";
            strTable = "tblProjectConsolidate";
            LST.EPP.stcEpp.exportToByteArray(new DataTable[] { dt }, strPathDest, strTable: strTable, blnSave: true);
            // ** Project consolidate
            // ** tblProjectConsolidate



            dt = @"SELECT Status, Count(Status) Count 
                    FROM tbl_Project_Tasks 
                    {0} 
                    AND ISNULL(Status, '') <> '' 
                    GROUP BY Status"
                .fwFormat(strPID)
                .fwSqlFillDataTable();
            dt.TableName = "Task status";
            strTable = "tblTaskStatus";
            LST.EPP.stcEpp.exportToByteArray(new DataTable[] { dt },
                strPathDest, strTable: strTable, blnSave: true);
            // ** Task status
            // ** tblTaskStatus



            dt = @"Select Status, COUNT(Status) Count 
                    FROM tbl_Project_Details 
                    {0}
                    GROUP BY Status"
                .fwFormat(strPID)
                .fwSqlFillDataTable();



            dt.TableName = "Project status";
            strTable = "tblProjectStatus";
            LST.EPP.stcEpp.exportToByteArray(new DataTable[] { dt },
                strPathDest, strTable: strTable, blnSave: true);
            // ** Project status 
            // ** tblProjectStatus




            dt = @"Select Category, COUNT(Category) Count 
                    FROM tbl_Project_Details 
                    {0}
                    GROUP BY Category 
                    ORDER BY Count"
                .fwFormat(strPID)
                .fwSqlFillDataTable();
            dt.TableName = "Project categories";
            strTable = "tblProjectCategories";
            LST.EPP.stcEpp.exportToByteArray(new DataTable[] { dt },
                strPathDest, strTable: strTable, blnSave: true);
            // ** Poject categories
            // ** tblProjectCategories



            dt = @"Select Area, Count(Area) Count 
                    FROM tbl_Project_Details 
                    {0}
                    GROUP BY Area 
                    ORDER BY Count"
                .fwFormat(strPID)
                .fwSqlFillDataTable();
            dt.TableName = "Project areas";
            strTable = "tblProjectAreas";



            return LST.EPP.stcEpp.exportToByteArray(new DataTable[] { dt },
                strPathDest, strTable: strTable);

            // ** Project areas
            // ** tblProjectAreas



        }



        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public string getReportOptions()
        {
            string dtArea = ("SELECT DISTINCT AREA FROM tbl_Maint_Area").fwSqlFillDataTable().fwDistinctValues();
            string dtCategory = ("SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY FROM tbl_Maint_Category").fwSqlFillDataTable().fwDistinctValues();
            string dtStatus = ("SELECT DISTINCT STATUS FROM tbl_Maint_Status").fwSqlFillDataTable().fwDistinctValues();
            string dtUsers = ("SELECT DISTINCT USERNAME FROM tbl_Maint_User").fwSqlFillDataTable().fwDistinctValues();

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                Areas = dtArea,
                Categories = dtCategory,
                Status = dtStatus,
                Users = dtUsers
            });
        }

        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public string fillParams(string users, string categories, string status, string areas)
        {
            Session["rep-users"] = users;
            Session["rep-categories"] = categories;
            Session["rep-status"] = status;
            Session["rep-areas"] = areas;



            return "";
        }

    }

}
```

This is the .aspx.cs of export: export.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace BORA
{


    public partial class export : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] arr = null;

            try
            {
                clsBORA report = new clsBORA();

                arr = report.generateReport();



                Response.Clear();
                Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"BORA Scorecard.xlsx\"");
                Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie("fileDownload", "true"));

                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.BinaryWrite(arr);


                //Response.End();
            }
            catch { /* DO NOTHING */ }

            finally

            {
                if (arr != null) Array.Clear(arr, 0, arr.Length);

                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The aspx file named: export.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="export.aspx.cs" Inherits="BORA.export" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Queries are correct, html part is ok, works correctly but it keeps downloading wrong data, aside that, how can I print a byte array?

Anything else I should add?

Also, how can I print that ".fwswlfilldata".

Again, I am new to programming, love it, wanna learn, but sometimes I need help with these things.

Thank you very much

Comment: How are you displaying results.  The common reason for this type issue is the view is not getting repainted.  I often have this issue with a DGV displaying results of the SQL Qeury.  The query puts new results into the DataTable, but the DGV never gets updated.

Comment: Hi, results are displayed send straightly to a xlsx file, then downloaded to desktop. I don't have a view (no that I know of) for the data, it goes directly to a byte array then printed to the file. Is there a way of checking what is going to be sent to the file? I see that byte array, can't manage to print it.

Comment: If there is not data in the file then there is an issue with storing the files in the database.  Are you storing the files using UPDATE or INSERT?  Does the table in the database have a primary key?   If you have a primary key then you can have only one database with the same key.  You may of stored the files in the database with the same key which is causing the issue.  Or always getting the same file from the database.